# Query NTPD's monlist remotely?

Tags: time, ntp, ntpd

How do I query NTPD for monlist remotely? It would be nice to be able to keep track of what's happening with the time server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ntpdc` should work just fine from other computers but you'll need to remove the `noquery` restriction for that IP address.  If you have

```
restrict default kod noquery notrap nopeer
```

then you'll need to add a line like

```
restrict 192.168.1.55 kod notrap nopeer
```

to remove that noquery restriction for that IP address.  If you don't have any noquery restrictions anywhere, then `ntpdc -c monlist ntpserver` should Just Work.  Note that ntpd will ignore restricted requests, so the command will just time out if you don't have permission to query.